# How to count number of occurrences in a sorted text file

Tags: sorting, count, sortedlist

I have a sorted text file with the following format:

```
Company1    Company2    Date    TransactionAmount  
A            B            1/1/19   20000  
A            B            1/4/19   200000  
A            B            1/19/19  324  
A            C            2/1/19   3456  
A            C            2/1/19   663633  
A            D            1/6/19   3632  
B            C            1/9/19   84335  
B            C            1/23/19  253  
B            C            1/13/19  850  
B            D            1/1/19   234  
B            D            1/8/19   635  
C            D            1/9/19   749  
C            D            1/10/19  203200
```

Ultimately I want a Python dictionary so that each pair maps to a list containing the number of transactions and the total amount of all transactions. For instance, (A,B) would map to [3,220324].

The file has ~250,000 lines in this format and each pair may have 1 transaction up to ~10 or so transactions. There are also tens of thousands of pairs of companies.

Here's the only way I've thought of implementing it.

```
my_dict = {}
file = open("my_file.txt").readlines()[1:]
for i in file:
    i = i.split()
    pair = (i[0],i[1])
    amt = int(i[3])
    if pair in my_dict:
        exist = my_dict[pair]
        exist[0] += 1
        exist[1] += amt
        my_dict[pair] = exist
    else:
        my_dict[pair] = [1,amt]
```

I feel like there is a faster way to do this. Any ideas?